# Why is the domain of Sobolev spaces often defined to be open?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, sobolev-spaces

Ususally Sobolev spaces are defined for open domains but in some cases it would be handy to define them on compact domains. It doesn't actually matter, no? Because the boundary at the end is nothing but a set of measure zero. Or why do they bother to distinguish between open or not open sets here anyway.

Comment: The problem is not the Sobolev space itself, but the space of test functions on $\Omega$.